# Is there a way to exit a nested function without stopping all executions?

Tags: r, function

Is there a way to exit a sub-function without exiting all functions in R? For example, in the below reprex, I'd like to be able to see `everyone should see this` even when I pass `exit` to `test_check_wrap()`

```r
test_check_wrap <- function(x) {
  
  test_check(x)
  print("everyone should see this")
  
}

test_check <- function(x) {
  
  if (x == "exit") {
    
    stop("specified to exit test check")
    
  } else {
    
    print("hello!")
    
  }
  
  print("Only things that pass through will see this")
  
}

test_check_wrap("continues")
#> [1] "hello!"
#> [1] "Only things that pass through will see this"
#> [1] "everyone should see this"
test_check_wrap("exit")
#> Error in test_check(x): specified to exit test check
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: just change `stop` to `print`

Comment: You can use `return()` to exit a function without throwing an error. If you want info on more advanced usage, see the [Conditons chapter of Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/conditions.html).

Comment: This will print out NULL in the console.  How do you use return() to exit a function quietly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tryCatch()` in `test_check_wrap()`:

```
test_check_wrap <- function(x) {
  
  tryCatch(
    test_check(x),
    error = \(err) {}
  )
  print("everyone should see this") 
}
```